# How to create a datatable in xsd file using c#

Tags: c#, datatable, xsd

I need to create a datatable by writing code in xsd file not by using exixting datatable in xsd file.when right click on xsd file---Add---Datatable.
But I don't want to use this,I want to write some code for creating the datatable.
I am not getting idea to solve this problem,please help in solving this.
Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you need to do. Are you sure you're talking about `xsd` and not `xls`? Do you want a datatable in a Schema file? For validating an XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `DataTable`:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.TableName = "Sample";

dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
dt.Columns.Add("Column2");
dt.Columns.Add("Column3");
dt.Columns.Add("Column4");

dt.WriteXmlSchema(@"D:Project1\example.xsd");
```